# Check if a circle is within an ellipse

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I have an ellipse centered at $(h,k)$, with semi-major axis $r_x$, semi-minor axis $r_y$, both aligned with the Cartesian plane.

How do I determine if a circle with center $(x,y)$ and radius $r$ is within the area bounded by the ellipse

Comment: Evaluating inequalities: a point $\;(a,b)\;$ withing the circle (i.e., the disk) fulfills $\;(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2\le r^2\;$ ...now, you have to check if this is within the ellipse. It's hard to say anything more in such a general case.

Comment: The inside of ellipse is where $\left({x-h\over r_x}\right)^2+\left({y-k\over r_y}\right)^2$ is less than 1. Now write the parametric equation for your circle, maximize the said function over it, and check the maximum. If it is under 1, then you are inside.

Comment: @Ng Chung Please do not edit the question as to render  comments/answers that have already been given hard to understand.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Fine, but at least keep the Latex format and also **correct the bugs for major and minor axes**, they were the same!  Otherwise, just simply *roll back*.

Comment: @Ricardo, what've you tried and where did you get stucked?  Please show your own efforts.

Comment: @NgChungTak That's exactly what I did: simply to roll back.

Comment: The problem would have been much easier if both the circle and the ellipse were concentric.

Comment: Hope OP uses $( p,q)$ etc. symbol as center of circle

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can set the origin at the ellipse center. This simplifies the equations.

Comment: Yes we can simplify the problem setting the Ellipse centered at (0,0). I'm doing an algorithm that creates circles with random center positions (x,y) with a know radius. I need to check if those random circles are completely, or just touching the ellipse, not crossing over it. at the moment, i'm trying to positionate they inside of the ellipse, but with no sucess.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: doing a translation we can suppose than the circle is centered at $(0,0)$. Parametrize the equation of the ellipse:

$$x(t) = h + r_x\cos t,$$
$$y(t) = k + r_y\sin t.$$
And find the maximum and minimum of $t\mapsto x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $x$ or $y$ from

$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{r_x^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{r_y^2}=1$$

and

$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{r^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{r^2}=1 . $$

If the point of intersection is complex due to quantity under radical sign (discriminant) being negative, then the circle is inside the ellipse.

If it is zero, the circle touches the ellipse and if posive there is intersection between them at 2 or 4 points.

Comment: Do we have a Simple way to check this? i tried to Solve the equation, but it get a kinda big.

Comment: Groebner basis solution may be helpful when equations are not linear

Answer (score 0):

An ellipse and a circle are both on 2d space.
the ellipse is centered at $A$ and the circle is centered at $B$
first find the vector between them $B-A$ call it $D$
Make a variable $N$ that is the normal of $B-A$

We know that the strait line from the circle to the ellipse is where the circle is closest subtract the Normal times the radius from $D$

Solve for the intersection of an ellipse.

In code it would look like this:

```
var dx = circleX-ellipseX;
var dy = circleY-ellipseY;
var d = 1/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
var nx = dx*d;
var ny = dy*d;
dx -= nx*circleRadius;
dy -= ny*circleRadius;
//Ry is ellipse height
//Rx is ellipse width
if(Ry*Ry*dx*dx + Rx*Rx*dy*dy < Rx*Rx*Ry*Ry){
    score += 10;
    food[0] = width+15;
}
```

Comment: would be to good if this worked.. ;P

Comment: I guess you would need a case for if the distance between them was less than the radius

Comment: I just reduced the radius of the ellipse, X and Y now by the circle's radius. And just checking if the mid-point is inside the "smaller" ellipse.. works for this use-case.. maybe not for all..